# UITableView does not handle contentOffset correctly when scrolling/paging

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a table view over very large amount of data. 
For performance reasons, it can't be loaded all at once.
More, sometimes random place of array should be loaded, so incremental pagination is not good option.

The current solution to these requirements is sliding window over data array. As user scrolls, I add cells from one end and remove from opposite end. I use scroll position (by looking at what cells are going onscreen) to determine whether it's time to load new data.

Usually, when you call `tableView.deleteRows(at:with:)` and remove cells from the beginning of table, tableView adjusts its `contentOffset` property so user still see same cells as before operation.

However, when tableView is decelerating after scrolling, its `contentOffset` is not adjusted on updates, and this causes loading new pages over and over until deceleration is completed. Then, on first update after deceleration, `contentOffset` is fixed by tableView and loading stops.

Same thing occurs when scrolling back and adding values at the beginning of table with `tableView.insertRows(at:with:)`.

How can I make UITableView adjust its contentOffset properly?

OR are there other ways to overcome this bug -- keeping the ability to load arbitrary piece in the middle of data array and scroll from it?

I made a tiny project illustrating the bug:

https://github.com/wsb9/TableViewExample

Comment: Are you just trying to invert the scrolling? What is the end goal of this exercise? Also what is preventing it from loading all at once? Dequeuing a cell should be reusing a cell already in memory

Comment: Or are you trying to create infinite scrolling that loops around? I’m confused as why you would want to add / remove rows from the top / bottom

Comment: My suggestion is create operation queue !! , Create operation when new cell appears and cancel operation when cell goes out of screen.

Comment: I downloaded your sample project. When I execute it on the iPhone 8 Plus simulator, it does scroll smoothly in both directions. So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sample project, I can understand is you are trying to implement infinite scroll through the window content concept so that you can always have fixed number of rows (index paths ,lets say 100) so that when window scrolls down/up - table view remove indexPaths from top/bottom accordingly.
And even though you have more data source item you can always have tableView of indexPaths 100

Basically you are dealing with two problem here:

1. ContentOffset
2. Dynamic height

Let's assume we have height is fixed (44) and table is not inverted.
To implement Window for infinite scrolling you have to do following:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let bottom: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
        let buffer: CGFloat = 3 * 44
        let scrollPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.y

        if (scrollPosition > bottom - buffer) {
            dataSource.expose(dataSource.exposedRange.shift(by: 25))
            self.tableView.contentOffset.y -= self.dataSource.deltaHeightToRemove
        }
    }
```

- Decide how much height buffer you need to keep when scroll goes down. This height buffer is the height after which you decides to insert some more item (25) into the datasource.
- At this point you now have to remove items from the top
- As you remove item from top you are basically telling scrollView to reduce it's content-offset by same height.
- In this way total content size will be fixed every time

  Hope it will help.

  **EDIT:-**
  Here is the modified code which actually does infinite scroll at bottom of 
  table view with dynamic cell height. This doesn't increase the rows count more than 100. but still loads data in sliding window.
  [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzk9RboMm8jLVHZ0bWtDOFdfanc)

Answer (score 2):

From your sample project, I can understand the following,

- One thing is you want to increase performance of your table view by only loading few number of cells at a time
- Your second concern is sometimes you want to load table view with data that randomly placed in data source array

I checked your code and you have implemented your `sliding-window over data-source model` very interestingly. The problem caused because of you had been trying to make `tableview` efficiently by removing and readding cells.

Actually the Dequeuing a cell should be reusing a cell already in memory. Please take a look at the apple documentation,

> For performance reasons, a table view’s data source should generally
>   reuse  UITableViewCell  objects when it assigns cells to rows in its 
>   tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)  method. A table view maintains a queue or
>   list of  UITableViewCell  objects that the data source has marked for
>   reuse. Call this method from your data source object when asked to
>   provide a new cell for the table view. This method dequeues an
>   existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class
>   or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available for
>   reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method
>   returns nil.

The good news is your `sliding-window over data-source model` is working perfectly once I removed your row delete and readd mechanism. Here is your working code,

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2y_JJbzjRA6dDR3QzRMUzExSGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think what @Timex is looking here is kind of sliding window - fixed number of table view data source rows or items - which actually can slide over the large data set. In this way whenever you have more data items you actually remove same amount from already dequeued item and add new item again so that at the same index paths. This way your indexPaths will always be remain constant but you still be able to slide over.

Comment: But when I checked your link - since you are not doing any remove operation on data set- you data source count for tableView will always keep on creasing which will create more indexPaths as tableView will not find those indexPaths in dequeued cell - this is same as per doc - "This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.".